# boxBackgroundColor issue with TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox style

Tags: material-components, material-components-android

I am trying to make a TextInputlayout with Outlinedbox style. But when I use boxBackgroundColor to have background in just inner box, the floating label showing grey background. Don't know, from where it is coming.

My code for textinputlayout is:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_password"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"

    app:boxBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"
    app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/layout_username"
    app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:hint="@string/prompt_password"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:nextFocusForward="@id/checkCredentials"
        android:selectAllOnFocus="true" />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Check this image for output:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9uMk.png)

Please help me with this issue if anyone knows about it.